# Simulate Left Click, Cursor Position, and Timing

Tags: c#, mouseevent, sendmessage

I am building a .Net 4.0 application (using Winforms) that uses `mouse_event` to simulate left clicks (I know `mouse_event` is deprecated, but this problem occurs when I use `SendMessage`, as well).

In conjunction with the simulated left clicks, I also set the cursor position in the application (I've tried `Cursor.Position`..., as well as `SetCursorPosition()`).

The problem is the timing.  I'll make a call to set the cursor position, and later in the code, I make a call to left click.  But often, the order of these actions go out of order (left click occurs before the navigation).  I've tried to correct for this by putting in various pauses (`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()`, wrapping actions within a `Task` object, etc).
None of these solutions are working, and I'm sure my lack of understanding about how Windows messaging works is playing a role in this problem.

So, my pseudocode would look something like this:

```
navigate(x_pos, y_pos);
leftClick();  ///using mouse_event()
navigate(x_pos2, y_pos2);
leftClick();
```

In the above example, the events would occur out of order, where the 2 navigate calls occur first, then the 2 `leftClick()` calls happen after that.

For the mouse_event (leftClick), I basically use:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = StdCall)] 
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
```

...Then I use the 0x02 (mouse down) and 0x04 (mouse up) calls to simulate a left click For setting the cursor position, I tried a WinAPI call, as well as simply using

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(...);
```

Comment: Is your application single-threaded? And could we see the guts of your `navigate` and `leftClick` functions? I'm asking because `SendMessage` is a blocking, synchronous call and the behavior you're describing could only happen if messages are being sent from multiple threads.

Comment: The application is not opening up separate threads.  For the mouse_event (leftClick), I basically use:
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

...Then I use the 0x02 (mouse down) and 0x04 (mouse up) calls to simulate a left click

For setting the cursor position, I tried a WinAPI call, as well as simply using Cursor.Position = new Point(...);

Comment: @TimC: Please don't paste code into comments. Edit your post instead.

Comment: @Cory: Although it looks like a dupe the OP's problem isn't with sending a click or setting the cursor's position. It is with unexpected behavior when the clicks and moves occur.

Comment: @PaulSasik: Fair enough; close vote retracted.